# How to change font size and theme on VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

why is my code not being executed/processed?

`.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 24,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 18,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Noctis Minimus",
}
```

what's wrong with my VS code, is there a setting to do or it's just not my day?

(I already download the noctis btw, but still can't be processed)

(I already save it using shortkey or manually, but still won't work)

Comment: Follow: https://console-logs.netlify.app/logs/vscode-themes/

Comment: @Trees the OP does not want to create a Theme, he wants to change the used Theme

Comment: can you change the theme with `Ctrl+K Ctrl+T`, does it work if you change it in the global `settings.json` file